# How do I add transparent Pixels without just doing white pixels?

Tags: javascript, html, css, graphics, transparent

I Just made a little pixel art app and I ran into a problem while I was trying to fix the eraser tool.  When I try to erase with the color 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)' it does nothing, so I am forced to settle with the color white. Do you guys know what I might be doing wrong? (I'm also having another issue so I will ask about that when this one is answered)  [Here is the project](https://jsfiddle.net/Rubedog/k4s2zrbo/21/) And below is the code for the project:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var pixelSize = 10;
var color = "#000000";
var eraser = false;
var fillStack = [];

var fillButton = document.getElementById("fill");

fillButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    processFillStack();
});

var downloadButton = document.getElementById("download");

downloadButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute("href", dataURL);
    link.setAttribute("download", "pixel-art.png");
    link.click();
});

var widthInput = document.getElementById("width");
var heightInput = document.getElementById("height");
var resizeButton = document.getElementById("resize");

resizeButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    canvas.width = widthInput.value;
    canvas.height = heightInput.value;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
});

document.getElementById("eraser").addEventListener("change", function() {
    eraser = this.checked;
});

canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
    if (!fillButton.pressed) {
        var x = Math.floor(e.offsetX / pixelSize);
        var y = Math.floor(e.offsetY / pixelSize);
        if (eraser) {
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,.1)";
        } else {
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
        }
        ctx.fillRect(x * pixelSize, y * pixelSize, pixelSize, pixelSize);
    }
});

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
    if (e.buttons == 1 && !fillButton.pressed) {
        var x = Math.floor(e.offsetX / pixelSize);
        var y = Math.floor(e.offsetY / pixelSize);
        if (eraser) {
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,.1)";
        } else {
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
        }
        ctx.fillRect(x * pixelSize, y * pixelSize, pixelSize, pixelSize);
    }
});

var imageInput = document.getElementById("image-input");

imageInput.addEventListener("change", function() {
    var file = imageInput.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        };
        img.src = e.target.result;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});



function floodFill(x, y, fillColor) {
    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var pixelStack = [[x, y]];
    var pixelPos, rowStart, rowEnd, up, down, i;
    while (pixelStack.length) {
        pixelPos = pixelStack.pop();
        rowStart = pixelPos[1] * canvas.width * 4;
        rowEnd = rowStart + canvas.width * 4;
        up = false;
        down = false;
        for (i = rowStart; i < rowEnd; i += 4) {
            if (matchColor(imageData.data, i, fillColor)) {
                continue;
            }
            if (matchColor(imageData.data, i, getPixelColor(pixelPos[0], pixelPos[1]))) {
                imageData.data[i] = fillColor[0];
                imageData.data[i + 1] = fillColor[1];
                imageData.data[i + 2] = fillColor[2];
                imageData.data[i + 3] = fillColor[3];
                if (pixelPos[1] > 0) {
                    if (matchColor(imageData.data, i - canvas.width * 4, getPixelColor(pixelPos[0], pixelPos[1] - 1))) {
                        if (!up) {
                            pixelStack.push([pixelPos[0], pixelPos[1] - 1]);
                            up = true;
                        }
                    } else if (up) {
                        up = false;
                    }
                }
                if (pixelPos[1] < canvas.height - 1) {
                    if (matchColor(imageData.data, i + canvas.width * 4, getPixelColor(pixelPos[0], pixelPos[1] + 1))) {
                        if (!down) {
                            pixelStack.push([pixelPos[0], pixelPos[1] + 1]);
                            down = true;
                        }
                    } else if (down) {
                        down = false;
                    }
                }
                if (pixelPos[0] > 0) {
                    if (matchColor(imageData.data, i - 4, getPixelColor(pixelPos[0] - 1, pixelPos[1]))) {
                        pixelStack.push([pixelPos[0] - 1, pixelPos[1]]);
                    }
                }
                if (pixelPos[0] < canvas.width - 1) {
                    if (matchColor(imageData.data, i + 4, getPixelColor(pixelPos[0] + 1, pixelPos[1]))) {
                        pixelStack.push([pixelPos[0] + 1, pixelPos[1]]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
}


function matchColor(data, i, color) {
    return data[i] == color[0] && data[i + 1] == color[1] && data[i + 2] == color[2] && data[i + 3] == color[3];
}

function getPixelColor(x, y) {
    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(x * pixelSize, y * pixelSize, pixelSize, pixelSize);
    var r = 0, g = 0, b = 0, a = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < imageData.data.length; i += 4) {
        r += imageData.data[i];
        g += imageData.data[i + 1];
        b += imageData.data[i + 2];
        a += imageData.data[i + 3];
    }
    var n = imageData.data.length / 4;
    return [Math.round(r / n), Math.round(g / n), Math.round(b / n), Math.round(a / n)];
}

function processFillStack() {
    var threads = 4; // number of threads to use
    var stackSize = fillStack.length;
    var chunkSize = Math.ceil(stackSize / threads);
    var chunks = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
        chunks.push(fillStack.splice(0, chunkSize));
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
        (function(chunk) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                for (var j = 0; j < chunk.length; j++) {
                    var x = chunk[j][0];
                    var y = chunk[j][1];
                    var color = chunk[j][2];
                    floodFill(x, y, color);
                }
            }, 0);
        })(chunks[i]);
    }
}
```

```css
canvas {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#color-picker {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
/*  position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px; */
}
#download {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

label, input, button {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

label {
    font-weight: bold;
}

input[type="number"] {
    width: 50px;
}

button {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#eraser {
    display: none;
}
#eraser + label:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
#eraser:checked + label:before {
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

<input type="color" id="color-picker">

<input type="checkbox" id="eraser">
<label for="eraser">Eraser</label>

<button id="download">Download</button>

<label for="width">Width:</label>
<input type="number" id="width" value="20">
<label for="height">Height:</label>
<input type="number" id="height" value="20">
<button id="resize">Resize</button>

<button id="fill">Fill</button>

Import Image:
<input type="file" id="image-input">
```

I was trying to convert the colored pixels into completely transparent ones but I ended up with the color white or nothing.

Comment: And what type of visualization do you expect for a completely transparent pixel?

Comment: A canvas is just that, it behaves like a real life canvas. Once you put paint on it, you can’t erase it, you can only paint over it. If you paint over something with clear (transparent) paint, of course it will have no visible effect.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen when you download and then view the pixel art after erasing something it will currently just display white where you erased, what I want to happen is to just have no content in that white space, I might be able to fix this by using a converter while the user downloads the image but Idk how to do that either

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like others have said, `fillRect` will paint on top of what's already there, not replace. That lets you mix transparent colours together like on a real canvas.

You can just use `clearRect` to erase.

Change the event listeners in `mousedown` and `mousemove` to:

```js
    if (eraser) {
      ctx.clearRect(x * pixelSize, y * pixelSize, pixelSize, pixelSize);
    } else {
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.fillRect(x * pixelSize, y * pixelSize, pixelSize, pixelSize);
    }
```

From the [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect):

> The `CanvasRenderingContext2D.clearRect()` method of the Canvas 2D API erases the pixels in a rectangular area by setting them to transparent black.

Demo:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var pixelSize = 10;
var color = '#000000';
var eraser = false;
var fillStack = [];

var fillButton = document.getElementById('fill');

fillButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
  processFillStack();
});

var downloadButton = document.getElementById('download');

downloadButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.setAttribute('href', dataURL);
  link.setAttribute('download', 'pixel-art.png');
  link.click();
});

var widthInput = document.getElementById('width');
var heightInput = document.getElementById('height');
var resizeButton = document.getElementById('resize');

resizeButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
  canvas.width = widthInput.value;
  canvas.height = heightInput.value;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
});

document.getElementById('eraser').addEventListener('change', function () {
  eraser = this.checked;
});

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
  if (!fillButton.pressed) {
    var x = Math.floor(e.offsetX / pixelSize);
    var y = Math.floor(e.offsetY / pixelSize);
    if (eraser) {
      ctx.clearRect(x * pixelSize, y * pixelSize, pixelSize, pixelSize);
    } else {
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.fillRect(x * pixelSize, y * pixelSize, pixelSize, pixelSize);
    }
  }
});

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
  if (e.buttons == 1 && !fillButton.pressed) {
    var x = Math.floor(e.offsetX / pixelSize);
    var y = Math.floor(e.offsetY / pixelSize);
    if (eraser) {
      ctx.clearRect(x * pixelSize, y * pixelSize, pixelSize, pixelSize);
    } else {
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.fillRect(x * pixelSize, y * pixelSize, pixelSize, pixelSize);
    }
  }
});

var imageInput = document.getElementById('image-input');

imageInput.addEventListener('change', function () {
  var file = imageInput.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (e) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    };
    img.src = e.target.result;
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});

function floodFill(x, y, fillColor) {
  var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  var pixelStack = [[x, y]];
  var pixelPos, rowStart, rowEnd, up, down, i;
  while (pixelStack.length) {
    pixelPos = pixelStack.pop();
    rowStart = pixelPos[1] * canvas.width * 4;
    rowEnd = rowStart + canvas.width * 4;
    up = false;
    down = false;
    for (i = rowStart; i < rowEnd; i += 4) {
      if (matchColor(imageData.data, i, fillColor)) {
        continue;
      }
      if (
        matchColor(imageData.data, i, getPixelColor(pixelPos[0], pixelPos[1]))
      ) {
        imageData.data[i] = fillColor[0];
        imageData.data[i + 1] = fillColor[1];
        imageData.data[i + 2] = fillColor[2];
        imageData.data[i + 3] = fillColor[3];
        if (pixelPos[1] > 0) {
          if (
            matchColor(
              imageData.data,
              i - canvas.width * 4,
              getPixelColor(pixelPos[0], pixelPos[1] - 1)
            )
          ) {
            if (!up) {
              pixelStack.push([pixelPos[0], pixelPos[1] - 1]);
              up = true;
            }
          } else if (up) {
            up = false;
          }
        }
        if (pixelPos[1] < canvas.height - 1) {
          if (
            matchColor(
              imageData.data,
              i + canvas.width * 4,
              getPixelColor(pixelPos[0], pixelPos[1] + 1)
            )
          ) {
            if (!down) {
              pixelStack.push([pixelPos[0], pixelPos[1] + 1]);
              down = true;
            }
          } else if (down) {
            down = false;
          }
        }
        if (pixelPos[0] > 0) {
          if (
            matchColor(
              imageData.data,
              i - 4,
              getPixelColor(pixelPos[0] - 1, pixelPos[1])
            )
          ) {
            pixelStack.push([pixelPos[0] - 1, pixelPos[1]]);
          }
        }
        if (pixelPos[0] < canvas.width - 1) {
          if (
            matchColor(
              imageData.data,
              i + 4,
              getPixelColor(pixelPos[0] + 1, pixelPos[1])
            )
          ) {
            pixelStack.push([pixelPos[0] + 1, pixelPos[1]]);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
}

function matchColor(data, i, color) {
  return (
    data[i] == color[0] &&
    data[i + 1] == color[1] &&
    data[i + 2] == color[2] &&
    data[i + 3] == color[3]
  );
}

function getPixelColor(x, y) {
  var imageData = ctx.getImageData(
    x * pixelSize,
    y * pixelSize,
    pixelSize,
    pixelSize
  );
  var r = 0,
    g = 0,
    b = 0,
    a = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < imageData.data.length; i += 4) {
    r += imageData.data[i];
    g += imageData.data[i + 1];
    b += imageData.data[i + 2];
    a += imageData.data[i + 3];
  }
  var n = imageData.data.length / 4;
  return [
    Math.round(r / n),
    Math.round(g / n),
    Math.round(b / n),
    Math.round(a / n),
  ];
}

function processFillStack() {
  var threads = 4; // number of threads to use
  var stackSize = fillStack.length;
  var chunkSize = Math.ceil(stackSize / threads);
  var chunks = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
    chunks.push(fillStack.splice(0, chunkSize));
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
    (function (chunk) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        for (var j = 0; j < chunk.length; j++) {
          var x = chunk[j][0];
          var y = chunk[j][1];
          var color = chunk[j][2];
          floodFill(x, y, color);
        }
      }, 0);
    })(chunks[i]);
  }
}
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#color-picker {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
/*  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px; */
}
#download {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

label, input, button {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

input[type="number"] {
  width: 50px;
}

button {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#eraser {
  display: none;
}
#eraser + label:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
#eraser:checked + label:before {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

<input type="color" id="color-picker">

<input type="checkbox" id="eraser">
<label for="eraser">Eraser</label>

<button id="download">Download</button>

<label for="width">Width:</label>
<input type="number" id="width" value="20">
<label for="height">Height:</label>
<input type="number" id="height" value="20">
<button id="resize">Resize</button>

<button id="fill">Fill</button>

Import Image:
<input type="file" id="image-input">
```

Comment: This works! Thank you for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

As I see here, when you simulating the eraser effect. You're using a semi-transparent color which is `rgba(255,255,255,.1)`. I think that this semi-transparent color is mixing with the white background of the canvas so that it causes you a white area.

Much better, you use `globalCompositeOperation` here with the value `destination-out`, so new drawings are drawn only in the areas where the existing drawings are transparent.

In your `mousedown` and `mousemove`, set the `globalCompositeOperation` property to `destination-out` when the eraser tool is active.

In the below code, `globalCompositeOperation` is set to `source-over` after each drawing operation so that subsequent drawings are drawn normally;

```
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
  if (!fillButton.pressed) {
      var x = Math.floor(e.offsetX / pixelSize);
      var y = Math.floor(e.offsetY / pixelSize);
      if (eraser) {
          ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
          ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";
          ctx.fillRect(x * pixelSize, y * pixelSize, pixelSize, pixelSize);
      } else {
          ctx.fillStyle = color;
          ctx.fillRect(x * pixelSize, y * pixelSize, pixelSize, pixelSize);
      }
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
  }
});

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  if (e.buttons == 1 && !fillButton.pressed) {
      var x = Math.floor(e.offsetX / pixelSize);
      var y = Math.floor(e.offsetY / pixelSize);
      if (eraser) {
          ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
          ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";
          ctx.fillRect(x * pixelSize, y * pixelSize, pixelSize, pixelSize);
      } else {
          ctx.fillStyle = color;
          ctx.fillRect(x * pixelSize, y * pixelSize, pixelSize, pixelSize);
      }
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
  }
});
```

Then, when displaying the final image, you need to draw the original canvas onto itself using the `globalCompositeOperation` property and set to `destination-out`. This will remove the erased areas from the original drawing;

```
function displayFinalImage() {
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
  ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
}
```

This should allow you to erase with any color, including `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)`, and still see the erased areas as transparent.